# Powershell | DownloadString | External website | Return

Tags: powershell

I'm a totally powershell newbie, so please be indulgent ;)

I'm trying to write a script where a machine check an external website waiting for a the word: "test" to execute a download. The things goes like this:

```
$Word = 'test'
$WebClientObject = New-Object Net.WebClient
$comment = "http://MySite.wordpress.com/comment_section/"
$WebClientObject.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36)")

While($True) {
  $CommentResult = $WebClientObject.DownloadString($comment)
  $Found = $CommentResult.contains($Word)

  If ($Found) {
    IEX $WebClientObject.DownloadString('http://A_Server_That_Is_Accessible/Tasks_to_do')
    #Task_to_do and some blabla commands
    Return
  }
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
}
```

*I'm running powershell 2.0. Windows7*

**What happened:**

- the download is not executed over internet
- it is not a issue coming from IPs or paths

**What I've done next:**

- I directly write the different commands in the powershell prompt:

**-->** the While($True) initiate an endless loop without exiting it.

To make the trick I need to "double click return on my keyboard", the loop's ending and the "downloadstring" command is finally executed.

Still remember I'm more than a newbie, right? :(

- I tried *"break"* *"return"* or *"exit"* bu impossible to quit the
  loop.
- I tried to put many double carriage return in my script also without
  any success.

Would someone please indicates me the way to do this simple thing...? :)

Thanks a lot.

**UPDATE**
Those little lines should be utilize by different persons in different places (that's one of the reason of a deported website), and i just do not have possibility to update the remote machines to a newer version of powershell. 
If anybody have any Microsoft powershell guru in his contact, it will be just a tremendous help. Thank you all guys.

Comment: I dont really understand what you are trying to do... You download a webpage, search for a String and if found, you are downloading other page? Is that what you want to achieve? Why are you looping over and over with while loop? If found, download the file and thats all, right? Now you are doing it infinitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's a simple example of what I think you are trying to do:

```
$Path = New-Object System.Uri("http://localwire.pl/");
$WebClient = New-Object Net.WebClient;
$Word = "PhraseThatDoesNotExist"

While ($True){

    $Result = $WebClient.DownloadString($Path);
    $Found = $Result.Contains($Word);

    If ($Found){
        $Path = New-Object System.Uri("http://stackoverflow.com");
        $NewResult = $WebClient.DownloadString($Path);
        Write-Host "Found!"
        Break;
    } Else {
        Write-Host "Not found!"
    }
    Start-Sleep -s 5
}
```

We are downloading one webpage and if it contains phrase we were looking for, we are downloading the other page. I hope I understood you right. If not, please let us know what exactly you need.

Comment: Thank you for your answers and to be more clear:

I want a word written on a web page triggers the download of a file from another remote machine. The idea is to be able to drive from point A, point B for it to go look for information at a point C.

I use a while loop to point B is always "listen" to the instructions given by point A. I want this operation can be in the repeat time. 
But I do it probably very awkwardly. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Ok I've edited the code, so now it waits 5s to check again. It's not the most beautiful idea to be honest but does what You want.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solves the problem. I stay in an infinite loop that will take control of systematic way. 

What I need is a key word for example "test" that triggered action download. once, but the machine is listening to the next order of download. I hope not to be too confusing.

Comment: to be more precise and less complicated:
as all this seems over my level: When I initiate a while loop in my powershell prompt recess I have this symbol >> that appears (waiting for more arguments). I finished my loop with a "}". But the symbol >> is still there. I am obliged again to press the return key on my keyboard to play the order. How can I make that from a script and not from the powershell prompt? I tried to put "Return" (in my initial script) after the "}". Nothing. Neither with "Break" or "Exit" instead of "Return".

Comment: i also tried to put 'r or 'n at this end of my script with no more success..

Comment: You're trying out something that is not so easily achieved through a website. You would need a web service to which your powershell script registers and wait for event. Another way is to make Powershell listen on TCP or UDP port (depends on how reliable it needs to be) and some other application should send some message that app will understand as a trigger if proper.

Comment: As for your second question: you want to exit loop if $Found == $False? If so, script will end after leaving While loop.

Comment: In reality the idea could be summarized in a few words. I am able to parse the page of a website, and that the existence of a specific word triggers the download of a script on the remote machine. So I can give my clients the opportunity, with a grid of keywords, to download the scripts they even need them.

Comment: as I host the scripts to download I do not encounter problem in rights and files are accessible. I serve it at the moment with a simple SimpleHTTPServer for my tests and I do not encounter difficulties with that.

Comment: my first script should be able to do the trick. When I write it line by line in my powershell prompt, and I click two times the "return button of my keyboard" at the end to get out of the loop, everything seems to be executed. But once on the web, without having the opportunity to double click it's another story ...

Comment: Ok, I made a simple mistake out there.
Now it should be good.
It keeps on checking content of webpage provided. If not found, prints 'Not found!', waits 5s and tries again. If found, prints 'Found!', downloads other page provided and exists program itself.

Comment: Great. Your last post seems to do exactly what it have to do. I need now to make further configuration of course. Thanks a lot for the precious help ! :)